# How to Update RecordTypeId field in Lightning record form in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Hi @all I have lightning record edit form which are showing specific value one of them is a recordtype. I want to update the recordtype from the same as other fields are updating but when I click on recordtype field it shows me the below error:-
**[LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Field: RecordTypeId is not a valid lookup field.]]**

Answer (score 0):

Record Type change is a critical operation that messes everything up. Potentially you're looking at new page layout (incl required/readonly fields), new picklist dependencies... There's reason why you select it first before any layout is displayed. And why record type change is a special button, not a field visible on normal edit action.

If you know what you're doing, are confident the requirements won't change / you'll know how to represent the changed layouts, picklists etc...

1. Use [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) to pull (among others) the Map of record types.
2. Use this data to build `lightning-combobox` that onchange updates a helper variable (you'd ideally have that variable bound to `<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} record-type-id={recordTypeId}`
3. Have a custom `handleSubmit` in the record-edit-form in which you'd intercept the save, prepopulate the field and then submit.

Comment: Hi @eyescream Thanx for the reply. I have tried this one by putting adding record-type-id={recordTypeId}. I belief this shows us the field for the specific layout but what  I am doing here, I am showing specific field let say I want to show two fields for opportunity and that is accountId and RecordTypeId.. So I am using just two fields and So my question is that if This is possible to update the recordType from lightning record form or not ? If not then if you have any idea then Please do share here. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using <template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Opportunity" record-id="00603000003jFSrAAM">
         <lightning-input-field   field-name='RecordTypeId'  value="01239000000EGXN">  </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field   field-name='AccountId'></lightning-input-field> 
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
 </template> Please do let me know if i missed something.

Comment: I gave you an idea. Pull record types with "getObjectInfo" (or if you want - with `@wire` call to Apex and "describeSobject" method), use the returned data to make a picklist and display that picklist. Then on save silently copy the value over, like they show with `fields.Street` in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation "Overriding Default Behaviors"